# Remove Line in Pivot Chart for Blanks

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, pivot-chart

How do I get the forecast to not show the flat line in the past and also the actual to now show the flat line in the future?

[image: Pivot Chart]

Answer (score 4):

I test on Office 365, to hide the line in Pivot Chart for blanks, please right click the Pivot Chart > Select Data > Hidden and Empty Cells > Gaps > OK > OK.

The following picture shows the display of Pivot Chart for my sample.
[image]